What spatial curves have delta-invariant one?
Is it true that if a germ of a spatial curve $(C,x)\subset(\mathbb{C}^n,x)$ has $\delta=1$ and two irreducible components then it is isomorphic to an $A_1$ singularity?
I take the definition of the delta-invariant as in 1.2 of The Milnor Number and Deformations
of Complex Curve Singularities by Buchweitz and Greuel:
$$ \delta=\dim_\mathbb{C}\frac{n_*\mathcal{O_{\overline{(C,x)}}}}{O_{(C,x)}},$$
where $n:\overline{(C,x)}\rightarrow (C,x)$ is the normalization.
Edit: I know it is true for complete intersections, if it holds for any other contexts it would be much appreciated.

What about a curve with simple cusp?

Oops! Yes, 2 irreducible components then.

I actually want to ask about having a cylinder as a smooth fiber, which is equivalent to delta-invariant one and two irreducible components. So now it is fine.
